# Sentence construction: "This and this yield/s"

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I am writing the following sentence and would like to know which option is proper English (or if both are proper):

---

Option 1: Squaring both sides of (9) and dividing by 2 yields: 
[math equation]

Option 2: Squaring both sides of (9) and dividing by 2 yield: [math equation]

---

So the issue is "yield" versus "yields." Option 1 sounds better to me as a native English speaker.  The sentence was actually written by my non-native co-author in the option 2 form.  This made me wonder which is correct. Option 2 might be validated because both things together can be viewed as plural. Option 1 might be validated because the *procedure* of both things together is singular. Or perhaps both options are fine?

[Note that the "(9)" in the sentence refers to a numbered equation given earlier in the paper.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only the two actions taken together as a single unit that yields anything, so the singular is correct.  It's not like both of those operations taken each on its own will produce that same result.

Comment: Very nice and logical!  It is comforting to know that what sounded better to me was also correct.  Your answer was also _mathematically_ correct (indeed we need both operations together to get the result, either one alone will not work).  Thank you.

Comment: I agree. A non-mathematical example would be "Using good quality leaves, boiling the water properly and leaving the brew to infuse for the right length of time _makes_ a good cup of tea." Omitting any of the stages or completing them less than satisfactorily will not produce a good result, so it is a single, multi-stage process.